# Detect blow in Mic and do something

Tags: iphone, microphone

i found this [tutorial](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/) , and it's good , but doesn't work for me !

here is the code :

```
- (void)listenForBlow:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];

    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;

    if (lowPassResults > 0.95)
        NSLog(@"Mic blow detected");
 //change the background color e.g !
}
```

in the console show me the nslog reseult like this  (without any bowling !):

```
2010-04-11 23:32:27.935 MicBlow[2358:207] Mic blow detected
2010-04-11 23:32:27.965 MicBlow[2358:207] Mic blow detected
2010-04-11 23:32:27.995 MicBlow[2358:207] Mic blow detected
2010-04-11 23:32:28.026 MicBlow[2358:207] Mic blow detected
2010-04-11 23:32:28.055 MicBlow[2358:207] Mic blow detected
2010-04-11 23:32:28.086 MicBlow[2358:207] Mic blow detected
2010-04-11 23:32:28.115 MicBlow[2358:207] Mic blow detected
2010-04-11 23:32:28.145 MicBlow[2358:207] Mic blow detected
2010-04-11 23:32:28.175 MicBlow[2358:207] Mic blow detected
2010-04-11 23:32:28.205 MicBlow[2358:207] Mic blow detected
2010-04-11 23:32:28.236 MicBlow[2358:207] Mic blow detected
```

i change this value :

```
 if (lowPassResults < 0.95)
```

to

```
if (lowPassResults > 0.95)
```

so it seems work ! but doesn't chage anything , again if i put the background changing code the , my code change background but without any bowling !! 
what's the problem ?

Comment: "again if i put the background changing code the , my code change background but without any bowling" This makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: its working in simulator but not working in phone?? is there any settings to do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using it too and it works for me. You just have to play with the value to compare it with `lowPassResults`. Here's my code:

```
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];

    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  
    //NSLog(@"%f", lowPassResults);
    if (lowPassResults > 0.55)
        NSLog(@"Mic blow detected");
}
```

Comment: no its not working @ender. Please can u guide me. Same problem is coming. without blowing it change the bg color