# Detect a blow into the microphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, signal-processing, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

For a project of mine I need to detect when the user blows into the mic. I've following this tutorial: http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/ and this question: [Detect blow in Mic and do something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618317/detect-blow-in-mic-and-do-something)
But still I do not get the results I want. The blow is detected way too late, or sometimes not at all. When I tweak some results the blow is detected correctly, but then the blow is triggered too fast, ie. when you talk or make a clicking sound it is detected as a blow too.

Has anyone found a good way of detecting a blow? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AVAudioRecorder sound level API is not designed to give you reliable results in separating blowing sounds from other types of sounds received by the mic.

I suggest using the Audio Queue or the Audio Unit RemoteIO API, measuring RMS signal energy, envelope duration, and then using the Accelerate FFT library to check the spectrum for broadband noise vs. peaks that would suggest voiced talking instead of blowing.

e.g. a more reliable result will require a lot more work than 1 OS call.

Answer (score 2):

```
Use return as you get first lowpass results >0.55

I have solve the issue have a look.

-(void)readyToBlow1 { NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

NSError *error;

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

if (recorder) {
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder record];
    levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.01 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback1:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
} else
    NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}

(void)levelTimerCallback1:(NSTimer *)timer { [recorder updateMeters];

const double ALPHA = 0.05; double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0])); lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults; //NSLog(@"lowPassResults= %f",lowPassResults);

if (lowPassResults > 0.55) { lowPassResults = 0.0;

[self invalidateTimers];


NextPhase *objNextView =[[NextPhase alloc]init];

[UIView transitionFromView:self.view
                    toView:objNextView.view
                  duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                }
 ];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:objNextView animated:NO];

**return;**
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success using AudioQueueGetProperty() for the kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter.